# Suggest some good books to study uniform convergence of sequence of functions in Topological Vector Spaces

Tags: uniform-convergence, book-recommendation, topological-vector-spaces

I am trying to generalise a concept which I found in normed space to topological vector space. My concept needs the idea of Uniform convergence of sequence of functions in Topological vector space.  Please suggest me some good books that deal with series of functions and their uniform convergence in Topological vector space. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [**Topological Uniform Structures**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486658082) by Warren Page ([Bull. AMS review](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-06/S0273-0979-1979-14703-7/S0273-0979-1979-14703-7.pdf)). It might help to give an idea of what you're trying to generalize, however my gut reaction is that pretty much anything you can think of has probably been worked out by someone by the mid 1960s.

Comment: Thank you Renfro. I just went through the book you suggested. I didn't find the information I want to know. Actually I want to know how the convergence of sequence and sequence of functions is discussed in Topological Vector Space and when we say a series of functions is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Maybe the google search ["uniform convergence" + "filters"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uniform+convergence%22+%22filters%22) will be useful.